# run drupal site in github.io

Tags: mysql, github, drupal

I have one **Drupal** site in **RHC Openshift**, So i uploaded my site to one GitHub repository , So i interested in making one demo site via **GitHub.IO** server, So how could I establish this kind site via:

```
 <username>.GitHub.IO/<repository _name>
```

So i think which it's need to install at least ***MySQL*** in my GitHub repository .!!!
So how could I do this work?

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

To host sites on Github you need to use [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/). Github Pages is not a full-featured web host. It does not allow you to run any server-side code thus it is not possible to run a MySQL server on it.

Comment: No, not on github.io.